# HTML horizontal image scroll not working

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to have an image scroll horizontally on my web page but it doesn't work.

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="imgf">
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/1.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/1.JPG"></a>
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/2.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/2.JPG"></a>
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/3.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/3.JPG"></a>
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/4.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/4.JPG"></a>
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/5.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/5.JPG"></a>
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/6.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/6.JPG"></a>
    <a href="../assets/img/swe/7.JPG" target="_blank"><img src="../assets/img/swe/7.JPG"></a>
    </div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
    .imgf {
    background: #e6e6e6;
    box-shadow: -10px 0px 10px 1px #e6e6e6; 
    width: 40%; 
    margin-left: 42%;
    margin-top: -300px; 
    height: 300px; 
    overflow-x: auto; 
    overflow-y: hidden;
    }
```

I have tried `whitespace: nowrap` and many other things on the internet, but it just displays the images horizontally without being able to scroll.

Comment: You have `<br>` elements in your HTML... which, logically, create breaks, so no amount of CSS could force your images to be horizontal.

Comment: @FélixSaparelli really? http://jsbin.com/nozoyi/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Well, yes, okay, _everything is overridable_. Doesn't mean it's particularly easy nor recommended.

Answer (score 1):

## Horizontally align child elements into scrollable parent

this is the basic way to horizontally align inner elements inside an overflow parent

```css
.imgf{                  /* PARENT */
  overflow-x:auto;      /* Horiz scrollbar if needed */
  font-size:0;          /* remove 4px margin from inner inline-block elements */
  white-space: nowrap;  /* horiz-align inner child */
}
.imgf > * {             /* CHILDREN */
  font-size: 1rem;      /* Reset to 1-relative-em */
  display:inline-block; /* place next to each other */
  vertical-align: top;  /* since using inline-block elements */
  
  /*demo only*/background:#f00;width:400px;height:100px;border-right:1px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgf">
  <span></span>  
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
  <span></span>
</div>
```